# Manual Image Flip Code C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, graphics

I want to manually flip an image, I've two pictures boxes, I load original image in 1 box and operated in other, the algorithm I'm trying is to read original image from origin pixel and putting that pixel in the top right corner of a blank image and so on, my code is not working, whatever I do, it always throws an exception >_<
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

> ************** Exception Text **************
>       System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Parameter must be positive and < Height.
>       Parameter name: y
>          at System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel(Int32 x, Int32 y)
>          at ImageFlip.Form1.flip(Bitmap image) in c:\users\ahsan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ImageFlip\Form1.cs:line 43
>          at ImageFlip.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\ahsan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ImageFlip\Form1.cs:line 54
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

here is it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ImageFlip
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap temp;
            OpenFileDialog Dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            Dialog.Title = "Open an image file";
            if (Dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Dialog.FileName);
            temp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;

        }
        private Bitmap flip (Bitmap image)
        {
            Bitmap tp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
            int x, y;
            int w=image.Width, h=image.Height;
            int w = 100, h = 100;
            //MessageBox.Show(image.Width.ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show(image.Height.ToString());
            Color pix;
            for (x = 0; x <= image.Width; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y <= image.Height; y++)
                {
                    pix = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                    tp.SetPixel(w, h, pix);
                    h--;
                }
                w--;
            }                    
            return tp;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image = flip((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception? Please apply that to your question

Comment: See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Parameter must be positive and < Height.
Parameter name: y
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at ImageFlip.Form1.flip(Bitmap image) in c:\users\ahsan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ImageFlip\Form1.cs:line 43
   at ImageFlip.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\ahsan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ImageFlip\Form1.cs:line 54

Comment: Shouldn't w and h be 99 and not 100? (your for-loops go from 0-99)

Comment: I tried, still the same exception :'(

Comment: As posted you should go from `width - 1` an `height - 1` and also reset `h after each loop to `height - 1`. -  Obviously the is by far the __worst__ method to flip a bitmap. Look into [Image.RotateFlip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted rotates the image (if it is square, otherwise it will fail)

You need to reset `h` when starting to copy a column.

```
var w=image.Width - 1;
for (x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
{
    var h=image.Height - 1;
    for (y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        pix = image.GetPixel(x, y);
        tp.SetPixel(w, h, pix);
        h--;
    }
    w--;
 }
```

To mirror/flip the image over a vertical axis, simply omit `h` and use `y`:

```
var w=image.Width - 1;
for (x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        pix = image.GetPixel(x, y);
        tp.SetPixel(w, y, pix);
    }
    w--;
 }
```

To mirror/flip the image over an horizontal axis, omit `w` and use `x`:

```
for (x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
{
    var h=image.Height - 1;
    for (y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        pix = image.GetPixel(x, y);
        tp.SetPixel(x, h, pix);
        h--;
    }
 }
```

You can even remove `w` and `h` completely:

```
for (x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        pix = image.GetPixel(x, y);
        tp.SetPixel(image.Width - 1 - x, y, pix);
        // or
        // tp.SetPixel(x, image.Height - 1 - y, pix);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Cheers, that worked for me, thanks alot. First time this worked perfectly and I came to know that it is rotating the image by 180* degree, but I was supposed to mirror the image, for that what changing my code needs ?

Comment: In the SetPixel replace w with x or replace h with y, depending on what which way it should mirror

Comment: @AhsanAlii - I added mirroring and a simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

You're traversing from 0 to <= image.width (and height)

You should consider going from 0 and to < image.width (and height) instead. The error is because there is no pixel 100.

```
for (x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
```

Comment: still throwing an exception :'(

Comment: Just check your ranges, also the w and h parameters. What you're experiencing is that you're outside of the valid range of pixels. Try setting x = 1, y = 1 to see if that helps you. A width = 100 means valid pixels exist from 0 to 99. h needs to go back to 0 after each loop also

Comment: All parameter and values are valid according to me, yet getting exception
int x, y;
            int w=image.Width, h=image.Height;
            Color pix;
            for (x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
            {
                h = image.Height;
                w = image.Width;
                for (y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
                {
                    pix = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                    tp.SetPixel(w, h, pix);
                    h--;
                }
                w--;
            }                    
            return tp;